# Use uTLS object in HTTP request

Tags: go, ssl

I'm trying to use `utls.HelloChrome_Auto` from https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls. In the documentation it says to use the tlsConnection from uTLS, however i can't seem to figure out where it'd fit with the `net/http` library.